# xcode simulator error NSURLErrorDomain1202 using react-native-webview

Tags: xcode, react-native-webview, self-signed-certificate

I am using

- "react-native-webview": "7.4.3"
- "expokit": "^36.0.0",

When I run the app with the URL on the self signed certificate server, the error message will happen as below. If the URL is changed to server with proper issued certificate, no error will be shown.

```
Encountered an error loading page, Object {
  "canGoBack": false,
  "canGoForward": false,
  "code": -1202,
  "description": "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xxxxx.xxx.xxx” which could put your confidential information at risk.",
  "didFailProvisionalNavigation": true,
  "domain": "NSURLErrorDomain",
  "loading": false,
  "target": 265,
  "title": "",
  "url": "",
}
```

I have tried the following setting in the Info.plist

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>xxx.xxx.xx.xx</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

There is a [paragraph](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Custom-iOS.md#allowing-custom-cas-certifica-authorities-and-enabling-ssl-pinning) describing the self-signed cert, but not quite sure how to configure it. Does anyone has the idea about that?